# odd Brownie revert error

Tags: uniswap, brownie

I keep getting this error

```
VirtualMachineError: revert
Trace step 1206, program counter 176:
  File "contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol", line 7, in UniswapV2Factory.createPair:    
    contract UniswapV2Factory is IUniswapV2Factory {
        address public feeTo; **----> Not Highlighted; error here**
        address public feeToSetter;
```

I don't understand how this line can cause a revert error, I'm trying to create a liquidty pool using V2router02. when debugging the tx, the revert message is empty, and traceback outputs the above.

Here is the script:

```
    UniFactory = project.load(Path.home() / ".brownie" / "packages" / "Uniswap/v2-core@1.0.1").UniswapV2Factory
    global uni_factory
    uni_factory = UniFactory.deploy(accounts[0].address,
                                    {"from": accounts[0]})
    fee_to = uni_factory.feeToSetter()
    assert str(fee_to) == accounts[0].address

    global weth
    weth = WETH9.deploy({"from": accounts[0]})

    UniRouter = project.load(Path.home() / ".brownie" / "packages" / "curiousdweller/v2-periphery@1.2.0").UniswapV2Router02
    global uni_router
    uni_router = UniRouter.deploy(uni_factory.address, weth.address, {"from": accounts[0]})

    global dv_token
    dv_token = DamnValuableToken.deploy({"from": accounts[0]})
    dv_token.approve(uni_router.address, UNISWAP_INITIAL_TOKEN_RESERVE,
                     {"from": accounts[0]})
    uni_allowance_check = dv_token.allowance(accounts[0].address, uni_router.address)
    assert uni_allowance_check == UNISWAP_INITIAL_TOKEN_RESERVE

    deadline = chain.time() * 2
    assert deadline > chain.time()

    tx = uni_router.addLiquidityETH(dv_token.address, UNISWAP_INITIAL_TOKEN_RESERVE,
                               0,
                               0,
                               accounts[0].address,
                               deadline,
                               {"from": accounts[0],
                                "amount": Wei("9000 ether")})
```

Any ideas as to why the evm reverts?

This is what is at createPair:

```
function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair) {
        require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
        (address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
        require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2: ZERO_ADDRESS');
        require(getPair[token0][token1] == address(0), 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS'); // single check is sufficient
        bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
        assembly {
            pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1);
        getPair[token0][token1] = pair;
        getPair[token1][token0] = pair; // populate mapping in the reverse direction
        allPairs.push(pair);
        emit PairCreated(token0, token1, pair, allPairs.length);
    }
```

If it helps at all, i am trying to reimplement this level of damn vulnerable defi using brownie.
https://github.com/tinchoabbate/damn-vulnerable-defi/tree/v2.0.0/contracts/free-rider
I suspect that my current method of using project.main is causing some weird behaviour, so maybe there is a simpler way to reimplement this?

Comment: What is at `createPair`?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I've updated the question.